# Reactjs getting json data

Tags: json, reactjs

So I have this json file
info.json

```
{
    "experience":[
        {
            "title":"Pratt & Whitney Canada",
            "date":"September 2015 - December 2015"
        }
    ]
}
```

then I have my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Main from './main';
import Info from './info';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Main info={Info}/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

and then inside my main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Title from './title';

    const Main = () => (
        <Title Info={this.props.info.experience}/>
    );

    Main.propTypes = {

    }
    export default Main;
```

so when it gets render I get the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined`

basically what I want to do is a way to get the values inside my json file, pass it through my index.js so that I can then use it in different component.

Edit: title.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css'
const Title = (props) => (
  <div className="pos_left">
    <p className="titles">Someone</p>
    <p className="subtitles">3rd Year Software Engineer |  something</p> 
    <p>{props.data.experience}</p>
  </div>
  );

export default Title;
```

The problem I am having with this is that is not displaying anything
 or instead should I do `<p> {props.where} </p>`

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it throws you this error is because you are trying to use functional components.

While class components know about `props` (and `state` using `this`) automatically, functional components do not.

If you want to use `props` in a functional component, you need to pass `props` argument like this:

```
const Main = (props) => (
  <Title Info={props.info.experience} />
);
```

([More information about class and functional components on React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components))

Comment: thank you, it worked. also I was wondering when I do `info.experience` does it actually go and take the data inside of experience? and also could you explain what it actually does when you pass props as an argument inside that parenthesis

Comment: @user3450754 I added an explanation about functional components and differences between class and functional components. And yes `props.info.experience` takes data from `experience` in your json file, because you are passing the data using `info` prop.

Comment: so now if I want to use the data I passed into `<Title data={props.data.experience}` I added a snippet of code in my question, could you verify if that is the way?

Comment: Yes, it will display `experience` data inside your JSON file as long as `data` props content is whole JSON file. If you would pass only `experience` key (example: `<Main data={Info.experience} />`) then you need to pass data like this: `<Title data={props.data} />`

Comment: the problem I am having is that it is not displaying anything, I am not getting any errors also, so there must be something wrong in what I am doing

Comment: @user3450754 Seems like `experience` inside your JSON file is an array.

Comment: oh your right!! so would I use map to iterate through the array or how would I achieve that?

Comment: @user3450754 If you want to iterate through the array, you need to use `map` function. ([MDN documentation on map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map))